# Structuring Service and DAO Layers in Go

Tags: beginner, design-patterns, go

I am having a bit of difficulty in designing my Go code.

I'll try to demonstrate things with a very simple example of adding a new user to the database.

My Handler is only doing one thing: Calling a service.
The service is managing all the business logic and then calling the DAO to interact with the database.
The DAO also has only responsibility: Storing in the database.

Also, just for context I am making GraphQL requests to interact with my ElasticSearch database, but the design shouldn't be affected by this too much.

I have read a lot of posts about using structs/interfaces to handle the service layer and DAO layer, but I am unable to implement the same in my usecase.

`File: handlers/user.go`

```
type Resolver struct {
    client *elastic.Client
    index  string
}

func (r *Resolver) CreateUser(ctx context.Context, userID string, name string, token *string) (*model.User, error) {
    u, err := CreateUserService(ctx, r.client, r.index, userID, name, token)
    
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Could not add User to db")
        return nil, err
    }

    return u, nil
}
```

`File: services/user.go`

```
func CreateUserService(ctx context.Context, client *elastic.Client, index string, userID string, name string, token *string) (*model.User, error) {

    u := &model.User{
        UserID: userID,
        Name:   name,
        Token: token
    }

    s, err := utils.ParseToString(u)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    err := CreateUserDAO(ctx, client, index, s)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return u, nil
}
```

`File: dao/user.go`

```
func CreateUserDAO(ctx context.Context, client *elastic.Client, index string, user string) error {
    _, err = client.Index().
        Index(index).
        BodyString(s).
        Do(ctx)
    
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

I don't have a background in Java/C# so I'm not well versed with OOP Principles but I did read a lot on MVC based on other answers. My code works for now, but is it bad code?
What are the things I can smooth out?

I don't want to be passing parameters from one function to another. Is there a way to that with receivers on methods?

Comment: Welcome to code review. Asking `How to` questions is generally off-topic on code review because it indicates the code isn't working as expected, it is especially bad in a title. Since the code works it is important to change the title. A better title for this might be `Adding a new user through a service in Go`. The title should be about what the code does, any specific questions should be asked within the body of the question. Please review how to ask a good question in our [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: you should not be using functions everywhere. They do not offer any surface to build interchangeable api. They should be struct and methods. You should not pass around the clients etc. As you will have struct, you will be able to declare fields to attach those instances of clients to their respective service implementations and use them within the new methods. Those services are initialized early in your main and given to the handlers for consumption.

Comment: you dont `utils.ParseToString` but marshal something to a string. that step being tightly related to the underlying store, it should be within the elastic dao service. Consider tomorrow you want to record into rdbms, you need not to marshal that object to a string for storage.

Comment: @mh-cbon How can I write these structs and use them while passing? Could you write a small snippet to demonstrate this? I am having trouble understanding how to do this, hence my very last statement in the question.

Comment: show your main please

Comment: @mh-cbon the handlers are being hit by graphql, so there's no entrypoint as such. these function definitions are being automatically generated by gqlgen.

Comment: @mh-cbon I would really be glad if you provide some direction. Been stuck at this for 2 days.

Comment: i did. but it seems hopelessness.